# trigger resize event causes error $digest already in progress angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set resize active on my angualr js directive cause my dygraph always begin with scope.option.eidth = 0 even if I set the value.. after too many tries I found this:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

And in my browser it works ! But if i put this no my directive it raises the error

```
angular.js:11655 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

I know this is caused by scope state is in digest instead of apply.. is there a way to verify this?

My code:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('dashboard.view', []);

    app.directive('dygraph', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data    : '=',
                options : '=?'
            },
            template: '<div id="graphDiv" style="width: 100%"></div>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                var div = elem.children()[0];
                scope.options.width = elem.parent()[0];

                console.log("scope.$$phase ",scope.$$phase);
                var graph = new Dygraph(div, scope.data, scope.options);
                if(scope.options.title=="Scanning" || scope.options.title=="Bytes" || scope.options.title=="Pakets"){

                    graph.ready(function(){

                        if(scope.$$phase!='$diggest'){
                            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
                        }
                    });

                    console.log("scope.options.width 2",scope.options.width);
                }

            }        
        };
    });

})();
```